# While decoding the html entities from string, special characters display incorrectly

Tags: php, decoding

```
function decode_entities($text) {
    $text= html_entity_decode($text,ENT_QUOTES,"ISO-8859-1"); #NOTE: UTF-8 does not work!
    $text= preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me',"chr(\\1)",$text); #decimal notation
    $text= preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei',"chr(0x\\1)",$text);  #hex notation
    return $text;
}

echo decode_entities("For tiden er neste president i det afrikanske landet Burkina Faso 11 &aring;r
");

echo html_entity_decode("For tiden er neste president i det afrikanske landet Burkina Faso 11 &aring;r
",'UTF-8');
```

I am using the above function to decode HTML entities from the string but while decoding special characters are displaying incorrectly like `�`.
[Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/26c-anm)

Answer (score 1):

Try use a echo to force the displayed charset...

```
echo "<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
echo html_entity_decode("For tiden er neste president i det afrikanske landet Burkina Faso 11 &aring;r",'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the UTF-8 charset agrument for html_entity_decode works just fine. Tested on your phpfiddle script.
If it's not, try setting a content-encoding header using `header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');`

Considering the wrong parameter place in the example, the code that works for me looks like this:

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
echo html_entity_decode("For tiden er neste president i det afrikanske landet Burkina Faso 11 &aring;r", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I see that the code you're trying to use comes from the PHP manual page and is 9 years old. The behaviour of html_entity_decode has greatly been improved since, thus it works with UTF-8 encoding. The problem with the 2nd. call in your example is that you pass the UTF-8 parameter as the 2nd argument, not the third.